# Pass value from a controller to another one in post route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, session-cookies, session-variables

I have a user who must complete a field without to be logged in. The field is a email_field. 
I need to get the value of the email_field in my controller in order to send some documents, for this I tried to store the value of the email field in a session but when I inspect the session value it's egual to nil and I don't know why.

Here is the view with the form :

```
<%= form_with model: @email, local: true do |form|%>
    <% if @email.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error explanation">
        <h2>Erreur : </h2>
            <ul>
                <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
                    <li><%=message%></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag :email %> :
        <%= form.email_field :email, placeholder: "Insert your email" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-primary", value: "Go" %>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

My first step in my controller where I set up the session value :

```
def index
  session[:email] = Email.last.email
end
```

My controller where I have the post route :

```
def webhooks
    render status: 200
    session[:email].inspect -> nil
end
```

And my route file :

```
resources :emails

 get 'invoice/index' =>'invoice#index'
 post 'invoice/webhooks' =>'invoice#webhooks'
```

So here my question, how can I get the value from the session in this controller (the webhooks one) ? 
And am I on the right way while I try to do this or should I look for another solution ?

Comment: in your index-method, check the value of session after setting it if it is not nil.
>session[:email] = Email.last.email
>puts session[:email].inspect

Comment: I tried and it's not  nil, when I inspect I got the right email

Comment: Few things : if your user is submitting an email without being loggedin, there is no session. Why you don't store this email in a simple cookie ? Also I don't understand `session[:email] = Email.last.email` you are picking the last email in the Email model but this has nothing to do with the submitted email ??

Comment: Also tried with cookie and I have the same result. As I understood, Rails automatically generate a session when a user is on the application, that's why I tried with a session. the submitted email is the last email in the Email model as you follow a funnel, the email is picked just after filled the field. But I may be in the wrong direction, that's why I ask for help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you send documents just after creating the email

ie **emails_controller.rb**

```rb
...
  def create
  @email = Email.new(create_params)

  if @email.valid?
    @email.save

    send_documents(@email)
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
...
```

Where `send_documents` is a method that will trigger a mailer to send documents to the just created email.

Comment: Because I get the documents from a webhooks, that's why I have the route in `POST`, to get the information from the webhooks